# Translating and explaining Aramaic stipulations for an oath

Tags: translation, language, aramaic, nedarim-shevuot

Here is an example of the complexities of *Hilchos Shvuos*, excerpted from [an actual sworn oath](http://helbrans.blogspot.ca/):

> [image: הנני מבטל כל גילוי דעת או תנאי או מודעה ומודעי דנפקי מגו מודעי עד סוף כל מודעי ובפיסול עידי מודעה נגד השבועה שאשבע.‏]

What does the above mean? Please translate and explain each expression.

Comment: That's a crazy crazy crazy crazy shevuah, (the whole thing)

Comment: wow, its really really crazy just wanted to point that out again, especially the shtar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I hereby nullify any expression of intent or condition or disclaimer, and disclaimers that result from my disclaimers (lit. that come out from within) ad infinatum, and invalidate any witnesses of my disclaimer against the vow that I am about to make.

It is a declaration discounting any attempt to invalidate a vow, in order to make the vow absolutely binding with no way out.

גילוי דעת - One can perform actions that show that a vow is not really meant, by acting in such a way as to show the vow is unintended.  A possible example would be shaking your head no as you say it.

תנאי - One can make a condition based on which a vow is binding, such as "If I eat cheese tomorrow then the vow I am about to make is binding, but if not then it is not binding."

מודעה - one can be מוסר מודעה, make a declaration that what they are about to do is not being done seriously or is being forced upon them to do.